# Maintaining state with a TabBarController

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a TabBarController, that in it's first instance contains a ViewController for login purposes.

After a successful login another viewcontroller is pushed on.

I've noticed that if you select the tab again your returned to the top of the stack, What I would like to happen is your returned to the location you left.

Is this something that needs to be managed myself or is there a property or something to that effect that could be set.

Comment: Besides wasted resources for an unused login view, I'd remove the login view completely after use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manage that yourself by keeping state. You'd probably want to implement `shouldSelectViewController` in a `UITabBarDelegate` to get notified when the user clicks in the tab bar.
This is sent before anything is switched around.